# How to clear filtering on selection of a value from the combobox in ms access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, filtering, vba

I have a combobox that filters data on the form in the afterupdate event.
Following is the query I have been trying to use to filter data.This code filters data effectively but the problem that I am facing is that when I select "" from the combobox no data is displayed.What could be wrong?How can I display all the data of the form on selection of ""

```
Dim strCriteria As String
strCriteria = "[Jobno]='" & cboPMNO & "'"
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
If strCriteria = "<ALL>" Then
Me.FilterOn = False
ElseIf rst.NoMatch Then
MsgBox "No entry found"
Else
Me.FilterOn = False
Me.Filter = strCriteria
Me.FilterOn = True
End If
```

Comment: What is the Row Source of cboPMNO ?

Comment: There is some problem.I had typed when I select <ALL> enclosed in double quotes and not simply "".Enclosing in double quotes made it a blockquote I guess.

Comment: select distinct '<ALL>' as Jobno from tblmimain UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT tblMIMAIN.A_JOBNO AS Jobno FROM tblMIMAIN WHERE (((tblMIMAIN.A_LOCATION)>IIf(GetAsset()="**ALL**","a","ZZ") Or (tblMIMAIN.A_LOCATION)=GetAsset()) AND ((tblMIMAIN.A_SYSTEM)="NEN"));
I think instead of If strCriteria="<ALL>"  I should use If cboPMNO="<ALL>"

Comment: Also, instead of line no. 5 in the code above I tried this: Docmd.showallrecords and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim strCriteria As String
strCriteria = "[Jobno]='" & Nz(cboPMNO, "<ALL>") & "'"
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
If strCriteria = "<ALL>" or strCriteria = "" Then
    Me.Filter = ""
    Me.FilterOn = False
ElseIf rst.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "No entry found"
Else
    Me.Filter = strCriteria
    If Me.FilterOn = False Then Me.FilterOn = True
End If
```

Here's how I would normally write this kind of filter. I strongly dislike message boxes unless they are absolutely necessary. It's better to just show a blank form or listbox if there are no matches, in my opinion.

```
Dim strCriteria as String
If Nz(Me.cboPMNO, "<ALL>") <> "<ALL>" Then
    strCriteria = "[Jobno] = '" & Me.cboPMNO & "'"
End If
If strCriteria <> "" Then
    Me.Filter = strCriteria
    If Me.FilterOn = False Then Me.FilterOn = True
Else
    Me.Filter = ""
    Me.FilterOn = False
End If
```

Comment: It totally depends on how the combo box is programmed. You can allow blank entries. Backspacing all characters will result it a zero length string. But you're right, it's probably excessive protection for something that will never happen.

Comment: Also, the OP says: 'the problem that I am facing is that when I select "" from the combobox' It appears he's having some problem with zero length strings unless I misunderstood (which is very possible).

Comment: It seems far more likely to me that the OP is getting a null, not a zero length string, hence my request for the SQL of Row Source.

Comment: Yea, I think you're right. I've now planned for that possibility in both code examples.